# Tracking where a user has landed in a board game

Tags: c++

The idea of the program is that it simulates a game board with a user-inputted number of sides, and cells per side. The program then needs to simulate the user rolling two six-sided dice continuously until the starting tile is landed on or passed.

The problem I'm having is with a required function that records the spot the user landed on the most, per side of the game board (like a Monopoly board has 4 sides). For example, a Monopoly board with 4 sides, 10 cells on each side.

Side 1 has Cells 1 - 10

Side 2 has Cells 11 - 20

Side 3 has Cells 21 - 30

Side 4 has Cells 31 - 40

I'd need to report which cells I landed on the most for each of those four sides, or however many sides the gameboard has.

I have no idea how to start this function. I don't want the code to be written out for me, just a nudge in the right direction. As for the rest of the program, this is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int rollNDice(int nDice, int nSides) {
    int diceSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nDice; i++) {
        int randnum = 1 + (rand() % (nSides - 1 + 1));
        diceSum = diceSum + randnum;
    }
    return diceSum;
}

int mostLandings(const int boardVector, int startInterval, int endInterval) {
}

int main() {
    srand(333);
    int boardSides = 0;
    int boardSpotsPerSide = 0;
    int numberOfSims = 0;
    int diceMove = 0;
    int startInterval = 0;
    int endInterval = 0;
    const int boardVector = 0;

    cout << "How many sides of the board are there? ";
    cin >> boardSides;

    cout << "How many spots on each side? ";
    cin >> boardSpotsPerSide;

    cout << "How many simulations? ";
    cin >> numberOfSims;

    for (int i = 0; i < boardSides;) {
        const int boardVector = boardSides * boardSpotsPerSide;
        int spotsPerInterval = boardVector / boardSides;
        startInterval = spotsPerInterval / spotsPerInterval + (10 * i);
        endInterval = spotsPerInterval * (i + 1);

        mostLandings(boardVector, startInterval, endInterval)

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, this is my take on the problem. After the dice is rolled and you find the spot to land on, you just simply record that spot. The number of simulations implies the number of times the dice will be rolled and a spot taken? Then you'd have an array of that many times and a record of each spot that was landed on. Then iterate the array to find out how many times each spot was hit.

Comment: @DigitalNinja Not exactly. A simulation ends when you reach the end of the game board (like on a Monopoly board, this spot would be "Go"). How many rolls that takes is entirely dependent on the dice. And it's the spot you landed on the most, per side. A monopoly board for example has 4 sides with 10 spots each, so I'd be reporting four different 'most landed on' spots, all within different intervals. I also don't think the person I'm helping has learned arrays yet.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure, that's why I had that question mark. I think it would be difficult/messy to do without using an array. You could keep a running max count for each side (as in if spot 2 is landed on one more time than spot 3 then it becomes the most landed on spot and so on, for each side), but you don't know how many sides there will be.

Comment: is there a reason you have the `i++` at the end of the loop body instead of in the `for` ?

Comment: @RyanHaining My reasoning is probably flawed and it probably doesn't matter but I just wanted to make sure it didn't increment until after everything was done.

Comment: the last part of the for loop happens at the end [these two loops are equivalent](http://pastebin.com/CY5v8wJU)

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to start by calculating the total amount of squares on the board. The amount of squares q can be given by

> q = 2s + (s-1)(n-1) = sn + s- n + 1

where s is the amount of squares on each side and n is the amount of sides. Next, store each roll value and loop over the sum of the roll value and the player's previous position, and store those values in a separate array. Take each element in that array modulo q and store in a separate array. This array should be the index of each square landed on after each subsequent turn, which you can manipulate and read from as you like.